# How to include the jQuery and css library in a Spring-MVC Eclipse project

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

For my spring MVC project, I download jQuery and put it in my WebContent\WEB-INF\js folder. Then in my WebContent\WEB-INF\jsp\EditProfile.jsp file,

I need to importjs into my jsp page. Please help me [How to include the jQuery library in a Spring-MVC Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137128/how-to-include-the-jquery-library-in-a-spring-mvc-eclipse-project),
[How to include JavaScript library into Spring MVC project (jQuery or Dojo, for instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080287/how-to-include-javascript-library-into-spring-mvc-project-jquery-or-dojo-for-i)
But I did not help me.What are the changes in jsp page as well as spring-servlet.xml. Any jar is need for that.

Comment: have you include js file in JSP page by `<script type="text/javascript" src="... />` tag ?

Comment: yes I already use this

Comment: Post that code of JSP file.

Comment: yes,..I get the answer..... I am very thankful for helping me.